# Empty Data Getting After Json parsing in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

I am using calender with events it's working fine, all the events coming from JSON I can parse the JSON data stored in to array, if I can show the JSON Array its showing empty After scrolling the calender JSON Array showing the data, 
this is the code

```
var EventsData = [Event]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getdairyDetails()
}
```

inside the getdairyDetails()

```
if errorCode == "0" {

    if let event_list = jsonData["events"] as? NSArray {

        self.EventDates.removeAll()

        for i in 0 ..< event_list.count {

            if let event = event_list[i] as? NSDictionary {

                self.compareDate(date: (event["date"] as? String)!)

                self.EventsData.append(
                    Event(
                        eventId: event["eventId"] as? String,
                        eventName:event["details"] as? String,
                        eventDate: event["date"] as? String
                    )
                )
            }
        }
        self.do_refresh()
    }
```

if I can call this function

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {
    let dateString = self.dateFormatter2.string(from: date)
    print("this count first ",self.EventsData.count)
}
```

```
Result:
    this count first  0
    this count first  0
    this count first  0

After Scrolling the calender its showing 
    this count first  26
    this count first  26
    this count first  26
```

Comment: Post `do_refresh()` and the complete method `getdairyDetails()`

Comment: You need to format this code to make it legible enough to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try This Code

```
var  jsondarray = NSMutableArray()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getdairyDetails()
}



func getdairyDetails()
{

    var userDic : [String : AnyObject] = [:]

    if errorCode == "0" {

        if let event_list = jsonData["events"] as? NSArray {


            for i in 0 ..< event_list.count {

                if let event = event_list[i] as? NSDictionary {

                    self.compareDate(date: (event["date"] as? String)!)

                    userDic = [
                        "eventId": event["eventId"] as? String,
                        "eventName":event["details"] as? String,
                        "eventDate": event["date"] as? String
                    ]

                    jsondarray.add(userDic)
               }
            }
        }

        self.do_refresh()
}

func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {
        let dateString = self.dateFormatter2.string(from: date)
        print("this count first ",self.jsondarray.count)
}
```

Comment: I can try u r code after I'll debug the code,let task = session.dataTask(with:request,completionHandler:{(d,response,error) after exited from the func getdairyDetails()

Comment: soryy please add do_refresh function in after completion of for loop

Comment: Tq Bro it's working fine after implanted do_refresh function